# Rails how to route when a resource_id intentionally does not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am currently setting up a few internal pages that allow my customers to edit their billing info. However, all of the information is saved on Stripe.com except for a `stripe_customer_id` in my users table.

I setup the `/billing` controller, actions, and routes.

Now I'm trying to navigate to a `/billing/card` page, but I get this **ERROR** `missing required keys: [:billing_id]`.

Obviously I do not intend to have a "billing_id"/ billing table.

```
# routes      
resources :billing do
  get 'billing/customer_and_card', as: :card
end
```

I guess so far I have only dealt with objects/ resources that are stored in my database. How do I remove the need for a `resource_id` when routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not setting it as part of a resource.

Something like this:

`get 'billing/card', to: 'billing#controller_action_here'`